# Prime number and divisibility

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ be prime, prove that for any integer $r$, there at most $2$ solutions to the equation $x^2-r \equiv 0\pmod p$.

I don't understand the question as if $p=2$, and $r$ odd, then $x^2$ will need to be odd, and we have an infinite number of solutions.

Maybe this is true for $p>2$, but I don't really know how to prove it.

Comment: They mean solutions $\pmod p$.   Thus, if $p=7$  and $r=2$ the only solutions would be $3,4$.  For $p=2, r=1$ the only solution is $x=1$.

Comment: makes more sense! thank you - do you have any idea how to prove it though?

Comment: The mean solutions modulo $p$.  There are only $p$ classes.  If $p=2$ then are two possible $x$, $0$ and $1$.  Any other odd number is $\equiv 2 \pmod 2$.

Comment: ..... if $p = 2$ and $r=7$ then there is one solution mod $2$. $1^2 - 7\equiv 0 \pmod 2$ but $0^2 - 7 \not \equiv 0 \pmod 2$.  Any other odd number,say $253$ so that $253^2 - 7 \equiv 0 \pmod 2$ is the same solution as $253 \equiv 1 \pmod 2$.  In the $\mod 2$ system $253$ and $1$ are the same class $253 \equiv 1$.  So $1$ is the only solution.

Comment: For the record, If $x^2 \equiv r \pmod p$ then $(kp+x)\equiv r \pmod p$ so if there are any integer solutions there are an infinite number of *INTEGER* solutions, but we are not asking for integers solution but EQUIVALENCE solutions.  $kp + x \equiv x$ so they are the SAME solution.  It's only one, even though ther are an infinite number of *integers* that are all *EQUIVALENT* to the *one* solution.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253168/how-to-prove-that-the-number-of-solutions-of-x2-equiv-a-pmodp-is-0-or-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ and $x$ are solutions of $x^2 \equiv r \pmod p,$

then $x^2 - r \equiv x^2 - a^2 = (x-a)(x+a) \equiv 0 \pmod p$.

Since $p$ is prime, $p | (x-a)(x+a)$ means $p | (x-a)$ or $p | (x+a)$, i.e., $x \equiv a$ or $-a \pmod p$.

Thus, there can be at most two solutions.

Comment: As noted by others, it is possible there are no solutions.  For example $x^2 - 2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ has no solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The integers mod $p$ are a field.

In general, a polynomial of degree $n$ over a field has at most $n$ roots in the field.

Here $n=2.$

Comment: Do you think this question is being at a level where the student can be expected to prove that a polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ solutions? Or to take it as a given?

Comment: But +1 for bringing in ideas about what the question is actually asking and considering consequences.

Comment: I provided another answer, which is less abstract

Answer (score 0):

$x^2 \equiv r \pmod p$ and $0\le x < p$

$y^2 \equiv r \pmod p$ so that $y\ne x$ and $0 \le y < p$

$x^2 - y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$

$(x+y)(x-y) \equiv 0 \pmod p$.

Now $x \ne y $ so $x-y \ne 0$ and $|x-y| < p$ so $p\not \mid x-y$ hence $p|(x+y)$ but $0 < x+y < 2p$ so $x + y= p$

Now if we had a third option so that

$z^2 \equiv r \pmod p$ and $0 \le z  <p$ but $z \ne x; z \ne y; x\ne y$ we could use the exact same argument to conclude:

$x+y = x+z = y+z = p$.  But that would imply $z = y$ (and $y = x$ and $x = z$).

So $2$ distinct solutions is a possibility (but not a certainty!) but three distinct solutions is not.

(Bear in mind it's possible that there are no solutions.)

(Also not if $x$ is one solution then so is $p-x$ and if $p$ is odd then $x$ and $p-x$ are two distinct solutions. But that does not mean there is a solution at all.)

Comment: In the second line, did you mean $y \ne x$ and $0 \le$ **_y_** $\lt p$?

Comment: Yes, I did.......